# Finding two occurances of value in array with nothing in-between, or adjacent

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array where I want to check for all instances of a specific letter where there are empty values in-between, or they are adjacent.

```
let myArray1 = ['A',,,,,'A'] //function returns [0,5]
let myArray2 = ['A',,,'E',,'A'] //function returns []
let myArray3 = [,,'A',,'A','G'] //function returns [2,4]
let myArray4 = [,,'A','A','G'] //function returns [2,3]
let myArray5 = [,,'A','A','G','A'] //function returns [2,3]
```

I've been trying with a for loop and push to array but I'm getting muddled.

Any ideas on how to do this function?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and you will definitely get better response

Comment: are you sure you have to use empty values and not `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getMyResult(itemToSearch, array) {
    var firstIndex;
    var secondIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == itemToSearch) {
            if (firstIndex == null)
                firstIndex = i;
            else {
                secondIndex = i;
                break; // break loop as we got two success indices
            }
        } else if (array[i] != null) {
            if (firstIndex != null) {
                // something got in between the items
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (firstIndex != null && secondIndex != null)
        return [firstIndex, secondIndex]; // success indices
    return []; //not success
}

let myArray1 = ['A',,,,,'A'];
let myArray2 = ['A',,,'E',,'A']; //function returns []
let myArray3 = [,,'A',,'A','G']; //function returns [2,4]
let myArray4 = [,,'A','A','G']; //function returns [2,3]
let myArray5 = [,,'A','A','G','A']; //function returns [2,3]

console.log(
  getMyResult('A', myArray1)
);
console.log(
  getMyResult('A', myArray2)
);
console.log(
  getMyResult('A', myArray3)
);
console.log(
  getMyResult('A', myArray4)
);
console.log(
  getMyResult('A', myArray5)
);
```

The above function `getMyResult` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I chose this answer because it gave me an additional parameter for the ItemToSearch, although there was another answer that was more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.findIndex()` to find the first non empty value (ie: character) and its index in your array. You can then use `.findIndex()` again on your array to find the second non-empty value that appears after your first character. If the first character and the second character match then you can return the indexes, otherwise you can return an empty array:

```js
const getRange = (arr) => {
  const first = arr.findIndex(c => c !== undefined);
  const second = arr.findIndex((c, i) => i !== first && c !== undefined);
  
 return first !== -1 && arr[first] === arr[second] ? [first, second] : [];
}

console.log(getRange([,,,,,]));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,,,'A']));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,'E',,'A']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A',,'A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G','A']));
```

To optimize, you can do this with one-pass using a regular for..of loop by iterating the `.entries()` of the array;

```js
const getRange = (arr) => {
  let first = -1;
  let second = -1;
  for(const [i, char] of arr.entries()) {
    if(char !== undefined && first === -1)
      first = i;
    else if(char !== undefined && second === -1)
      second = i;
  }
  return first !== -1 && arr[first] === arr[second] ? [first, second] : [];
}

console.log(getRange([,,,,,]));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,,,'A']));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,'E',,'A']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A',,'A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G','A']));
```

Comment: very elegant solution

Comment: Yes, very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

if you for sure need empty values, than your only hope is using indexes:

```js
const res = ['A',,'E',,,'A']
  .reduce((acc, value, index) => {
    if(acc[value]) acc[value].push(index)
    else acc[value] = [index]
    return acc
  },{})
console.log(res)

// if you need just the elements that repeats:
const duplicate = Object.entries(res)
  .filter(([k, v])=> v.length > 1)
console.log(duplicate)

// if you need just an arbitrary element that repeats (as in your example)

const final = duplicate
  .map(([k,v]) => v)
  .find(() => true)
  
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to keep track of last value and its index, if last value is same as current value you can break the loop otherwise you can reset last value and start index.

```js
const getRange = (arr) => {
  let last = '', start = -1, end = -1;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]) {
      if(last === arr[i]) {
        end = i;
        break;
      } else {
        start = i;
        last = arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return end !== -1 ? [start, end]: []
}

console.log(getRange(['A',,,,,'A']));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,'E',,'A']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A',,'A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A','A','G','A']));
console.log(getRange([,,,'E',,'E',,,,,'E']));
console.log(getRange([,,'A',,'G','A',,,,,'A']));
console.log(getRange(['A',,,'E',,'A']));
```